# Docker Windows Containers CMD - Command not running

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, windows-server-container

I have a docker image that ends with the following CMD:

`CMD ["powershell", "c:\install\settings\install.ps1"]`

or

`CMD powershell c:\install\settings\install.ps1`

It did not execute (or perhaps the volume is not mounted yet).

Settings are placed in a mounted volume, and it is started with:

`docker run -d -p 80:80 --name openid --rm -v D:\settings\:c:\install\settings mydocker`

If I run the command after starting the docker image:

`docker exec openid powershell c:\install\settings\install.ps1`

It runs fine.

Is there a way of doing this?

Or is there a better way of deploying an IIS website with webdeploy and custom `SetParameters.xml`?

Comment: Have you tried to use ENTRYPOINT instead of CMD in your docker file or RUN as you try to install something? Have a look at http://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/ to see the fine differences (if needed)

Comment: I used DSC for prepping containers and IIS inside them. Relying on debugging DOCKERFILE execution is nightmare. DSC provides repeatable and more importangly debuggable way to deal with your application deployments. Details are here. https://github.com/artisticcheese/artisticcheesecontainer/wiki

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
# set up the shell
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]
CMD ["powershell", "c:\\\install\\\settings\\\install.ps1"]
```

> In Windows, the backslash is the separator in file paths, so we have
>   to escape it in Dockerfiles, otherwise it will be interpreted as a
>   line continuation. File paths then have double backslashes \, and the
>   single backslash is used for line continuation

from: https://blog.sixeyed.com/windows-dockerfiles-and-the-backtick-backslash-backlash/

Comment: I've added powershell setup line, can you check if that works? Otherwise, your full dockerfile would be useful.

Comment: Well no luck there either...

Full file (with minor changes to the paths are posted below.

Answer (score 0):

try this, might be a problem with the slash.

`CMD ["powershell", "c:/install/settings/install.ps1"]`

Comment: Do you have run multiple commands in your Dockerfile? Can you paste the content of your dockerfile(if  not confidential)?

Comment: `# Get windows`

`FROM microsoft/aspnet`

`# Install web deploy`
`COPY D:/WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi   /install/WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi`

`WORKDIR /install`
`RUN powershell start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList '/i c:\install\WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi /qn' -Wait`

`COPY D:/webdeploy/* /install/`

`CMD ["powershell", "c:\install\settings\install.ps1"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass PS script to docker command as this:

```
CMD ["powershell .\\myscript.ps1"]
```